# State is not updating when i tried hooks in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mui-datatable

I am a beginner to react js. When i tried hooks the state is not updating

defined state using useState like this:

```
 const [customerParams, setCustomerParams] = useState({
    name: '',
  });
```

Then I have to take values from onFilterChange function(filter change using mui datatable). I have to update the state with selected values .
This is my onFilterChange function:

```
     onFilterChange: (changedColumn, filterList, type) => {
    switch (changedColumn) {
      case 'Name':
        {
          if (filterList[0].length > 0) {
            const name = filterList[0].toString();
            setCustomerParams({ ...customerParams, name: name });
          }
        }
        break;

    }
  },
```

Here changedColoumn,filterList, and type will get by clicking filter and filterList[0]is the value of name. I have to update the state with seletcted name. But not Updating Please help me

Comment: First of all, a good practice is to split different local states with different useState. You code looks good otherwise. Check you indexes, they seems weirds, filterList[0] twice and filterList[4] at the final.

Comment: Please share [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code.

Comment: Is your code throwing any errors?

Comment: Also, FYI, you do not need the `{}` around your `case`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch